# Load Freebase full dump file to Virtuoso

Tags: freebase, virtuoso

I have downloaded the full RDF Freebase dump file 'freebase-rdf-2012-12-09-00-00.gz'(7.5GB) from this link http://download.freebaseapps.com/

This data dump uses the the Turtle RDF syntax as defined here http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_dumps

How can I load this file into Virtuoso (06.04.3132) ?

I tried to use this command

```
  SQL> DB.DBA.TTLP_MT (file_to_string_output ('freebase-rdf-2012-12-09-00-00.gz'), '', 'http://freebase.com');
```

but it finished in short time. The following request returned only 2 rows(triples) from the source file and no exceptions in the log.

```
  SELECT ?a ?b ?c from  <http://freebase.com> where {?a ?b ?c}

http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/american_football.football_historical_roster_position.number   
   http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.name  Number

  http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/american_football.football_historical_roster_position.number 
            http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.object.type  http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.property.

     2 Rows. -- 78 msec.
```

By the way,  how long may it take to load such a big file (8 GB RAM or 24 GB RAM)?

May this dump file be loaded in TDB (via tdbloader), Sesame OpenRDF(via load) or OWLIM SE repository without modification?
  And will I get a response from my SELECT SPARQL queries(not very complex) after loading in reasonable time after all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the reply from [freebase-discuss] mailing list:

This Freebase dump should be unpacked, splitted and run thru fix scripts. More details here

```
 http://people.apache.org/~andy/Freebase20121223
```

Comment: Andy's notes are about loading Turtle files, now the dump is provided in n-triples.